# ASP.NET MVC Application Insights Javascript Snippet preventing other JavaScript from working

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, azure-application-insights

I've just updated the `Content-Security-Policy` settings in the `Web.Config` file and added the [Application Insights JavaScript snippet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/javascript#snippet-based-setup) in my `_Layout.cshtml`.

Here is what the `Content-Security-Policy` in the Web.config looks like.

```
 script-src-elem 
    'self' 
    'unsafe-inline' 
    'unsafe-eval' 
     https://az416426.vo.msecnd.net/scripts/b/ai.2.min.js
     *.mymapjs.com
script-src 
    'self' 
    'unsafe-inline' 
    'unsafe-eval' 
     https://az416426.vo.msecnd.net/scripts/b/ai.2.min.js
     *.mymapjs.com
```

`mymapjs.com` is not longer working properly, my maps aren't showing up, and my browser is upset with me **yelling at me in red letters** with the error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'mymapjs.com' from origin 'mywebsite.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

When I remove the `https://az416426.vo.msecnd.net/scripts/b/ai.2.min.js` url from the `Web.config` `Content-Security-Policy` I get the warning:

> Refused to load the script 'https://az416426.vo.msecnd.net/scripts/b/ai.2.min.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src-elem 'self'                  'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://*.mymapjs.com  use.other.net use.other.net/ https://myfont.net/it.js

Answer (score 1):

It turns out I enabled the `enableCorsCorrelation = true` in the [Application Insights configuration.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/javascript#enable-correlation)
So then I tried updating the `correlationHeaderExcludedDomains` values with a wild card value for the `mymapjs.com`.

```
correlationHeaderExcludedDomains:
                    [
                        'myapp.azurewebsites.net',
                        '*.queue.core.windows.net',
                        '*.mymapjs.com'
                    ]
```

The wild card alone didn't work. I had to strictly type the JS libraries urls **AND** have the wildcard for it to work properly. It wants the scripts that are directly being requested from the `_Layout.cshtml` as well as the ones generated from the JS libraries.

```
correlationHeaderExcludedDomains:
                    [
                        'myapp.azurewebsites.net',
                        '*.queue.core.windows.net',
                        '*.mymapjs.com'
                        'https://mymapjs.com-core-events.js'
                        'https://mymapjs.com-services.js'
                        'https://mymapjs.com-ui-services.js'
                    ]
```

If anyone else gets caught up figuring this out, I hope this helps.